# How is a Line Represented in Epipolar Geometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d-reconstruction

The 3D reconstruction literature all mentions the following relationship:

> Given a point `m1` in the first image, the homogeneous coordinates of the epipolar line `l2` in the second image corresponding to `m1` are `l2 = Fm1`.

However, I can't get my head around what the coordinates of `l2` represent in old-fashioned cartesian coordinates (i.e., the image coordinates).  It's a single point, so how would I, say, physically draw the line on the image?

- Is it a vector direction from the epipole?
- Do `l2` and the epipole specify two points on the epipolar line?
- Is it something else that I'm not grasping?

I hope it's the third choice, because the other two don't seem to work out in my case.

Comment: Someone docked me a point, but didn't bother to tell me why.  The relationship is so ubiquitous in the literature that I can't imagine it's because the question isn't clear.  If it's because I apparently didn't do enough research, I did.  I've been trying to find an explanation for about a month now on my own.  The closest thing I could find is in Ch 9 of the (also ubiquitous) Hartley & Zisserman book (http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/).  There they talk about it being the cross product of m1 and the epipole (relative to the camera) - but that's a vector in 3D space, not on the image.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say the downvote was probably from someone who thought this question was off-topic, as its more of a math than a programming question.

Comment: I guess that's possible.  But this is where the questions for epipolar geometry and fundamental matrices seem to show up.  If there's a better place to ask it, I'd gladly ask it there.  And the implementation is definitely programming (specifically OpenCV/Python/Blender).  Would the Signal Processing group be better?

Comment: I actually did some work on this in my masters, but I've apparently forgotten it all. Try this link, I think its what I used to learn about it: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html

Comment: @code11, thanks for taking the time to reply.  I had already read that page, but I searched some more and found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~16385/lectures/Lecture18.pdf.
The coordinates of the line `l = Fm1` represent the line equation:

> `lxx + lyy + lz = 0`

So all I need to draw the line in image 2 are `l`, the epipole `e2`, and another (arbitrary) `x` value.

It's also somehow related to the cross product, since `l` also equals `e2 x m2`.  I don't really understand that part, though.